# sending email using "bcc" without "to" in java application

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have read all the reference in stackoverflow.  However, nothing matches in our goal.  How can i use **bcc** in sendmail method in java?

Answer (score 5):

According to the RFC for SMTP, RFC 2821 ([link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt)), it is not possible to send an email message without a `To:` header.  (You cannot send an `RCPT` command without it, see section 3.3.)

Comment: There are a bunch of good comments on that question like, "Can you show the code?"

Answer (score 1):

As Dietrich mentions, that's not possible with the RFC. If the primary goal is to send to the **bcc** target email addresses, you could provide a dummy **to** email address (such as your own email address or a reply-to email), which would fulfill that technicality while still allowing you to send the email to the desired bcc targets.

Answer (score 0):

msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress("joe@example.com"));

By default, JavaMail collects all the recipients specified on the Message object, including Bcc recipients, and uses them in the RCPT command to the SMTP server.  The Bcc recipients won't show up in the message headers, however (which is the whole point of Bcc).